# Where is the PatchGAN implementation in the official PyTorch CycleGAN repo?

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

There's mention in the paper and in the [code](https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix) comments of a 70x70 PatchGAN, although I can't find anywhere in the code this is explicitly implemented.

Does anyone know how it is implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. After the last conv layer of the PatchGAN (before average pool) the [receptive field size](https://medium.com/mlreview/a-guide-to-receptive-field-arithmetic-for-convolutional-neural-networks-e0f514068807) is 70. So each neuron on the single channel feature map (which is 30x30) coming out of that conv layer has information from a 70x70 patch of the input. The corresponding patches overlap one another on the input.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
A better link would have been this distill pub article: https://distill.pub/2019/computing-receptive-fields/
Edit: This answer might not answer the question but it has clarified my doubts. Thanks again for that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a single valued output for the discriminator, the PatchGAN architecture outputs a feature map of roughly 30x30 points. Each of these points on the feature map can see a patch of 70x70 pixels on the input space (this is called the receptive field size, as mentioned in the article linked above).

Each point on the output feature map represents the probability of how real the discriminator thinks is the receptive field of the particular feature point.
While training the discriminator the output feature map is compared with a 30x30 tensor of 1's for real images and a 30x30 tensor of 0's for generated/fake images.

The reason we do this is that the PatchGAN discriminator becomes more sensitive to the style of the image it looks at as compared to a discriminator that outputs a single value.